# To find the time offset between two differently sampled signals

Tags: discrete-signals

I got two sampled signals (samples at different rates ),how to find out the offset between them and to sync automatically  in Matlab

Answer (score 4):

Resample the signal at the lower rate to the higher rate, and then do a cross-correlation.